# R and R studio won't load aplpack

Tags: r, macos, package, macos-big-sur

I am using R/Rstudio (version 4.0.3 - "Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out") and have installed the aplpack package. However, when I go to load the package, it just loads forever without actually activating the package. I'm currently running macOS Big Sur 11.2 and I have the latest version of XQuartz installed. To load the package, I am using

```
library(aplpack)
```

I saw that someone else has had a similar problem, but they were running a different OS and their question was never answered. I'm hoping someone out there can help.

UPDATE: As was requested in the comments, here is the `Sys.info()` and the `sessionInfo()` information:

`Sys.info()

sysname
"Darwin"
release
"20.3.0"
version
"Darwin Kernel Version 20.3.0: Thu Jan 21 00:07:06 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.81.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64"`

`sessionInfo()

R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 10.16

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.3`

Comment: May you add `Sys.info()` & `sessionInfo()` output so others can get some more information about your system to give better answers?

Comment: @SinhNguyen, I've added that info to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install and open the aplpack package (macOS Big Sur 11.2) using `install.packages("aplpack"); library(aplpack)` but it did take some time to load (~2 mins). I suspect your issue is related to xquartz. Xquartz no longer comes installed with macOS, so a likely solution to your problem is to install an up-to-date version of xquartz (https://www.xquartz.org/releases/) and ensure it can be opened from RStudio using `x11()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reach the R - Mac  experts,
a posting to the ("good old") `R-SIG-Mac` (R Special Interest Group @ Mac) mailing list will reach them, notably the R Core team members involved:
https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mac